# wkwebview not respond on print action in swift iOS

Tags: webview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

WKWebview not responding for print function its working fine while trying from the browser but it's not working with WKWebview

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: there is no need for code we are just loading URL so after that everything handle by WKWebview it self. everything is working fine expect the print button.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did find any solution for that?